# Using <input type="file" > to load a directory in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

I need to upload a directory path  to a web application and change the Web.configuration on it.Updating the Web.config is done but the input file only takes files not folder.

I got the recommendation from friends to strip the File name and get directory path.But i feel it is against SOLID Principles

Am i right with It or SOLID principles don't work for UI Development.

I have used something like this

```html
<input type="file" >
```

---

Comment: You cannot get the full path of the file from a file input - it would be a security issue of you could

Comment: @StephenMuecke you used to be able to. IE < 9 would provide the full path. I think Firefox 2.0 in ~2006 was the first browser to obfuscate the file's path.

Comment: What do you mean by "upload a directory path"? Do you mean to upload an entire directory's files in a single go?

Comment: yes that is what the creators of the requirement have and i told them since we develop SOLID i believe it shouldn't be acceptable

Comment: SOLID has nothing to do with it. Its a [html specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#file-upload-state-(type=file)) that file inputs do not post back the path

Comment: is not using the folder of the file which we are selecting against SOLID.it is deriving a responsibility from the single responsibility of loading a file here single folder

Comment: @user2866998, I have no idea what your talking about (again SOLID has absolutely nothig to do with it). But it makes no difference. You CANNOT get the folder of the file a user has uploaded, nor can you specify a folder.

Answer (score -1):

As Pointed out SOLID has nothing to do with it and It would be a security Violation In doing so.Hence this shouldn't be done.

For if the sites is dependent on the Input It could actually coerce the site and hijack it based on the users input .If the User is malicious it could be detrimental for the site